# Shopify Theme & jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, shopify, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to integrate a small widget I created into my shopify theme. I've included all of the necessary resources however jQuery UI doesn't seem to work.

I get the following error in console:

**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).resizable is not a function**

I've tried including the files from both CDN and uploaded to theme using:

```
{{ 'filename.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

and

```
{{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js' |     script_tag }}

{{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js' | script_tag }}
```

using a simple init method:

```
  $('#objects img').resizable({
                handles : 'se',
                stop    : resizestop 
            }).parent('.ui-wrapper').draggable({
                revert  : 'invalid'
            });
```

Any help is appreciated as always,

Comment: Hi, can you give the link to your store. why you are including jquery, Your shopify theme should already have it. Maybe you are including jQuery twice which is causing conflict.

Comment: Another thing too. Why are you using code that is already years old and essentially out of date, expired, past due? jQuery for one is on version 3.

Comment: @DavidLazar ..just example markup

Comment: @MashR. only including jQuery once